# Properties of the permanent of a matrix

Tags: matrices, permanent

The permanent of a square matrix is known to have the following properties -

1. The permanent of the identity matrix is one.
2. For any permutation matrices $P$, $Q$, and matrix $A$, the permanent of $A$ equals the permanent of $PAQ$.

Is the permanent the only function of a square matrix that has these two properties? If not, what are some other examples?

Comment: A very simple example came to my mind is the sum of all the entries divided by the size.

Comment: So it in general should be some function that is invariant to row- and column- permutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely not true. Let $p(x_{11}, x_{12}, \cdots, x_{nn})$ be any symmetric polynomial of the variables such that $p(I)=1$ for the identity matrix (by abusing the notation, $I$ is identified with its entries), then $p$ satisfies both conditions: $PAQ$ is simply the result of switching rows and columns of $A$, so no entries have been changed. Further condtions are needed to characterize permanent.

Comment: Does it work for any nonsymmetric polynomials?

Comment: Yes. Consider $\prod_i (\text{sum of row } i) \prod_i (\text{sum of col } i)$. This definitely satisfies the two given conditions. And this is not symmetric, which can be seen from even the $2\times 2$ case: $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}\mapsto (a+b)(c+d)(a+c)(b+d)$, and if you swap $a,b$, you will have a different polynomial.

Comment: Very interesting. I wonder if there is a way to categorize all functions which satisfy the properties in the question.